# Getting API response from error HTTP calling

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get a response from an API. The API link contains the ID number of a subject. e.g. http.../a12
It will return an XML object as seen in Postman.

```
<Response>
    <code>200</code>
    <status>OK</status>
    <message>Completed</message>
    <messageCode/>
    <returnObj>
        <field1>0.25000</field1>
        <field2>0.01150</field2>
    </returnObj>
</Response>
```

However, if I sent an API where the ID does not exist in the database, let say, http.../g14, it will return this XML in Postman.

```
<Response>
    <code>400</code>
    <status>BAD_REQUEST</status>
    <message>ID is invalid.</message>
    <messageCode>RGN001</messageCode>
    <returnObj/>
</Response>
```

I can retrieve the first XML object without a problem, but I can't retrieve the 2nd XML which contain the error. My ASP client would return error 400, eventhough the XML is returned in Postman.

My code to retrieve the XML looks something like this

```
HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = setAuthHeader(endpoint);
wrWebRequest.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse wrWebResponse = wrWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; //it fails here.
```

Of course, the console return this error

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Alternately, I also trying another method

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic xxxxxxx";
var text = client.DownloadString(endpoint);
```

But this return the same error.

I just want to retrieve the 2nd XML response whenever I make an invalid HTTP call in which the response was custom made.

Thanks in advance for any guide and help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WebClient is designed to work that way. You can try to have a `try catch` block there in order to check if you received `400` but it only adds overhead.

I recommend you to use `HttpClient` which does not throw in case you receive a `400 Bad Request` response.

Documentation about `HttpClient` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8).